# Any "unix philosophy" tool to write/test/deploy Ethereum contracts?

Tags: dapp-development

I've tried Truffle several times already and I really appreciate their work, but for some me, I find it to be way too opinionated. It has a structure for building the whole app, including the HTML, CSS, migrations. For me, my client(s) are separate projects and I don't need migrations. I'd rather just separe those concerns and have a minimal tool that does only the Ethereum-related development:

1. Write an Ethereum contract;
2. Test it by deploying to a local testnet and calling its methods **from a separate JS file**;
3. Deploy it to the testnet/mainnet when it is done.

I'm quite lost trying to extract that minimal usage from the whole Truffle workflow. Is there any tool that does that, in an Unix-philosophy way, does that, only that, and does it well?

Answer (score 2):

If you speak Python you might feel more comfortable with Populus. It has migrations as a feature, but it doesn't force you to use them.

Comment: Populus is very UNIXy, but still, like Truffle, provides a lot of of structure with its default management command. If you don't like that structure you can directly call Populus Python APIs and not go through the command line client. I am doing exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to compile/deploy a contract I found is by using the [web3](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API) library from a `node.js` script. The following helper function deploys a solidity source code and returns the deployed contract object:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var Web3 = require("web3");
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

// Receives a solidity source code and the account, compiles/deploy
// the contract and calls the callback with the contract object.
function testDeploy(contractSrc, account, callback){
  var contractCmp = web3.eth.compile.solidity(contractSrc);
  var contractCon = web3.eth.contract(contractCmp.info.abiDefinition);
  contractCon.new({
    data: contractCmp.code,
    from: account,
    gas: 1000000},
    function(err, contract){
      if (!contract.address) return;
      callback(contract);
    });
};
```

You can then call its methods to test them. Example:

```
testDeploy(`
  pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
  contract HelloWorld {
    event Print(string out);
    function() {
      Print("Hello, World!");
    }
    function test() constant returns (int) {
      return 7;
    }
  }`,
  web3.eth.accounts[0],
  function(contract){
    contract.test({
      value: 0,
      gas: 200000,
      from: web3.eth.accounts[0]},
      function(err, result){
        console.log(result);
      });
  });
```

This outputs the bignum `7`, as expected.